# Python: Decision Tree Conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am trying to write part of my decision tree logic in Python. The data is coming from List 1 in dataframe 1 and List 2 and List 3 in dataframe 2. It states: if items in List 2 and List 3 are both found somewhere in List1 AND items in List 2 and List 3 side by side are NOT the same, then print out List 2 items. I am not sure how to approach this. Nested for loops? Or is there a function that would be best to use. If someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

`for items 2 in list 2 AND for items 3 in list 3:  for items 1 in list 1:  if items 2 == items 1 AND  if items 3 == items 1 AND  if items 2 = [x for x, y in zip(list 2, list 3) if x != y]: then print items 2 in a list`

Comment: Please read this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic will go something along this way

```
list_1 = df1["List 1"].values  # List 1 from DataFrame1
list_2_and_3 = df2[["List 2", "List 3"]].values  # List 2 and 3 from DataFrame2

for element in list_2_and_3:
    # element[0] is from List 2
    # element[1] is from List 3
    if element[0] in list_1 and element[1] in list_1:  # if both are present in the list 1
        if element[0] != element[1]:  # If they are not the same
            print(element[0])  # print List 2 items
```